# how to place ImageViews into RelativeLayout programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-relativelayout

I am placing several ImageViews (eggs) into RelativeLayout

[a link to image](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1PqmZb9ZxKp_N2yRVSpfg8sjorE-KXhlrvvkuisFPPb4/edit?usp=sharing)

I would like to have them all the same size aligned in the row, however if there is not enough place left for all of them RelativeLayout just shrinks on of them  and all the remaining ones are just omitted.

Is there any way how to tell RelativeLayout to resize them equally, so that all of them fit to the screen and have uniform size (intependent of the screen size and resolution)? 
it should look like this, however with all of them included:
(https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1H1Ij1hyxva2WVxb7HM6jNhju3VLeVn_W-mHhh3VHtJg/edit)

This is part of my code

```
private void testLoadEggs() {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(getContext());

    List<ImageView> imageEggs = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        imageEggs.add(new ImageView(getContext()));
        SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(this.getResources(), R.raw.white_egg);
        imageEggs.get(i).setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());

        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        if (i==0)
        {
            params.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        }
        else {
            params.addRule(RIGHT_OF,i-1);
        }
        imageEggs.get(i).setId(i);

        imageEggs.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        rl.addView(imageEggs.get(i), params);

    }

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params2.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    params2.addRule(CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    this.addView(rl, params2);

}`
```

the actual call:

```
    this.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#81D4FA"));
    this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    testLoadEggs();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding your views to RelativeLayout you can add them to LinearLayout with orientation="horizontal" and with each layout set to android:layout_weight="1"

Answer (score 0):

You should use Linear Layout and you can easily put your button or image with same size. For example;

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

or you can use more of them and put whatever do you want;

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:weightSum="100"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:layout_weight="30"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:layout_weight="30"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:layout_weight="30"/>
```